# text processing: replace configuration in dhcpcd.conf

Tags: bash, sed

I need to setup static IP for a device via script.  To do so, I need to process its `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file, which looks like this:

```
... blah blah

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.90.120
static routers=192.168.90.1

interface eth1
... blah blah
```

I need to remove all currently configured parameter of `eth0` and replace it with my own. So I will need to:

1. find the line that matches `^interface eth0`
2. remove matching line and all **none-empty** lines immediately below it, until an empty line or the end of the file is encountered
3. write my own config at the bottom of the file

How can I do this with standard linux command line tools such as `grep`, `sed`, as well as bash scripting.  I hope to **avoid** `python` or `perl` or any other programming languages.

### **EDIT**

As suggest in the comment:

1. My own config looks like:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24
static routers=172.16.1.1
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10
```

The key problem here is that the lines of configuration "block" is not fixed, it might be 3, 4 or 5 lines.  The only way I can think of is to use blank lines to set its "boundary".

2. My current solution uses a Go program to do the processing, of course that way I can do whatever I want.   But I would like to solve this problem using shell scripting and native linux tools only.  That's why I said I would like to avoid `python`, `perl` etc.

This is NOT a homework question.  I ask simply want to learn how to do multi-line matching using native tools -- if there is such an "elegant" way.  If there is not, fine, I can using programming languages to solve it.

**EDIT**

---

I did a few tests with the accepted answer, the last variant: sed with external config looks just what I want, so I do:

1. test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/d;$rmc.conf' dhcpcd.conf
```

2. mc.conf:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24
static routers=172.16.1.1
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10
```

3. dhcpcd.conf

```
# blah blah
interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.77.1.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.90.120
static routers=192.168.90.1
```

All three files in the current directory, the output of `test.sh` is:

```
# blah blah
interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.77.1.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

i.e. the content of `mc.conf` is NOT appended to output.  I can of course do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat dhcpcd.conf|sed '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/d'
cat mc.conf
```

But it is nice to know how to actually make the `r` command of `sed` work.

BTW, I am running Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: `write my own config at the bottom of the file` - Is it a single line config or a multi-line config? In which format does this config reside? as a file? as an env variable?

Comment: Add a minimal  example/desired output from your current post.

Comment: You could also add what have you tried so far, and where did it failed.

Comment: Please show your code and explain what is wrong with it, such that we can help. And also to avoid downvotes because of [what is explained here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: Linux is an operating system kernel. The only "Linux tools" are certain utilities from kernel.org, in the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package. All tools you see in a GNU/Linux distro are just that distro's selection.  `awk` and `sed` are described by POSIX; they are common to Unix-like systems (though not always with the extension you find in the GNU versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ mc="interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24
static routers=172.16.1.1
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10"
$ awk -v mc="$mc" '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/ {if(!/^$/) next} {print} END {print mc}' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
... blah blah

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0


interface eth1
... blah blah
interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24
static routers=172.16.1.1
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10
```

Explanations: we skip (`next`) all lines from the `interface eth0` line to the next empty line excluded, we print all other lines and at the end (`END` block) we print the content of `awk` variable `mc`. The `-v mc="$mc"` option declares `awk` variable `mc` and assigns it the value of the previously declared bash variable with same name.

Or, if you can store your own config in another file, say `mc.conf`:

```
awk '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/ {if(NR==FNR && !/^$/) next} {print}' /etc/dhcpcd.conf mc.conf
```

Explanation: `NR==FNR` is true only for the first file (`/etc/dhcpcd.conf`).

With `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/{
/^$/!{
$!d
s/.*//
}
}
$a\
interface eth0\
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24\
static routers=172.16.1.1\
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
... blah blah

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0


interface eth1
... blah blah
interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.1.100/24
static routers=172.16.1.1
static domain_name_servers=172.16.1.10
```

Explanations: delete (`d`) all lines from the `interface eth0` line to the next empty line excluded, print the others (the default with `sed`) and, at the end (`$`), append (`a`) the new configuration. There is a special case when the last line to delete is also the last of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`: in this case it is not deleted because it would end the processing before the new config is inserted. Instead it is replaced with an empty line.

Or, if you can store your own config in another file, say `mc.conf`:

```
sed '/^interface eth0$/,/^$/{
/^$/!{
$!d
s/.*//
}
}
$rmc.conf' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

(`sed` command `r` copies the contents of specified file to standard output).

If your `sed` is GNU `sed` and if you don't have `NUL` bytes in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` we can simplify:

```
sed -Ez 's/(^|\n)interface eth0\n(.+\n)*/\1/m;$rmc.conf' /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

`-E` for extended regular expressions, `-z` to slurp the whole file as one single line. With the `m` modifier of the substitute command periods don't match newlines.

Finally, if your entries are always separated by one or more blank lines, and you want to update several of them at once, GNU `awk` is probably a reasonable choice:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '
  FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {print a[$1]?a[$1]:$0}' mc.conf /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

We set the input record separator (`RS`) to the empty string, such that records are separated by empty lines. We set the output record separator (`ORS`) to 2 newline characters such that the same format is used for the output. We also set the input field separator to newline. The rest is quite simple: while parsing the first file (`mc.conf`) containing your new configurations we add each record to associative array `a`, indexed by the first line of the record. When parsing the second file, if a record has its first line that matches a key of array `a` it is replaced by the corresponding content of `a`. Else it is unmodified.

Comment: The last command, `$rmc.conf` does not work.   other than that, it works well

Comment: Did you create `mc.conf` and put your new config in it? I just tested with GNU `sed` and the BSD `sed` that comes with macOS and it works with both. What version of `sed` do you use? What happens, exactly?

Comment: I have added test result in the question

Comment: In your test the block you want to delete is the last of the file, different from the example in your question were it is followed by an empty line and some more stuff. So, in this case `sed` deletes the end of the file, including the last line, and stops there (this is how the `d` command works: if it deletes the last line the processing ends there). Let me fix that.

Comment: Done. The new versions (`awk` and `sed`, with or without `mc.conf`) delete up to the first newline excluded, now. Note that, with the non-GNU `sed` solutions, if the last line to delete is also the last of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` it is not deleted but replaced with an empty line.

Comment: Thanks, I will test the new version tommorrow. Currently I use a multi-step solution based on your answer, without the `r` trick.  The benefit is that I can control blank lines between interface blocks. As I have `wlan0`, `eth0` and `eth1` on the device, and all needs to be configured, I want to ensure there are blank lines in-between each config blocks.

Comment: @xrfang In my humble opinion you should consider a single GNU `awk` script to do all this at once. Let me add this.

Comment: Done. See the last part of the answer.

Comment: verified the last solution and worked well. thanks!